# SQLAlchemy db.create_all() doesn't create the tables when my models are defined in a separate file

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm somewhat new to Flask and I'm having a problem.

I have an app.py whereby I instantiated my Flask app and SQLAlchemy. (Code shown below):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'I5aE2js75KeZHVx88qAm4gPHnDvM7lSD'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.db')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Then on a separate file (models.py) I imported the db and used it as follows:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User {self.username}>'
```

The problem is when i use db.create_all(), the tables defined within my models.py file don't get created. I copied the classes over onto my app.py and they got created.

I dont know what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The model code has to be read by the interpreter _before_ `db.create_all()` is called.  So you could for example, move the call to `db.create_all()` to the end of your `models.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

I like to put my db initialization into a function:

models.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User {self.username}>'
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

from models import db

def initialize_db(app):
    app.app_context().push()
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'I5aE2js75KeZHVx88qAm4gPHnDvM7lSD'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.db')

initialize_db(app)
```